# Android Room Persistence Library: Handling errors

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to figure out how to handle errors with Room. I have the following interactor that inserts a task in the database:

`TaskInteractor.java`

```
public class TaskInteractor extends AbstractInteractor implements TaskContract.Interactor {

    final TaskRepository mRepository;

    interface Callback {
        void onSuccess();
        void onFailure(Throwable t);
    }

    @Inject
    public TaskInteractor(WorkerThread workerThread,
                             MainThread mainThread,
                             TaskRepository repository) {
        super(workerThread, mainThread);
        this.mRepository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertTask(final Task task, final Callback callback)
            throws SQLiteException {
        mWorkerThread.get().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mRepository.insertTask(task);
                } catch (SQLiteException exeption) {
                    Timber.e("Insertion failed. Exception: " + exeption.getMessage());
                    callback.onFailure(exeption);
                    throw exeption;
                }
                Timber.d("Insertion succeeded.");
                callback.onSuccess();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In `insertTask` I use a try-catch block to check if a `SQLiteException` happened. If it does, I throw the exception.
But is this a good way of handling errors or is there maybe a better way?

Comment: Hey, did you got the solution? I am also confused with same situation.